# How to set up a virtual host on ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu-18.04

I am trying to make to move to use Ubuntu for developing. I am working on an exciting Laravel project that is due to go live at the end of the month. I have cloned the repro and now trying to set up a virtual host ( my understanding is that you need this for the site work properly locally ). I have followed this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lkLAJd-Wb80&t=6s. But all I am getting is a 404 page not found. Hope someone can help with this.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html/myapp/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ServerName myapp.test

    ServerAdmin info@myapp
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myapp/public


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

I have also added myapp to the hosts file.

Comment: What have you tried? Did you set up an NGINX or Apache server? Are you using a virtual machine?

Comment: Its Apache. I have set my pc up as due boot. I have followed the video in the like i posted. Had a look at some others and they all seem to be the same.

Comment: What about `.env` file, did you make it after cloning? Also check fo `APP_KEY`

Comment: Yes I created the .env and generated a key

Comment: Show us your v-host configs

Comment: @NitishKumar I have updated the post.

Comment: Try  //myapp.test/public/index.php.  See if you get somewhere.

Comment: @nikistag Still getting 404

Comment: Directory path also goes with `public` folder, try  to edit this line with `<Directory /var/www/html/myapp/public>`

Answer (score 0):

You missed the `public` directory while defining the path in `<Directory>`. It should be something like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
        # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
        # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
        # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
        # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
        # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
        # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
        #ServerName www.example.com

        ServerAdmin info@myapp
        ServerName myapp.test
        ServerAlias myapp.test
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myapp/public

        <Directory /var/www/html/myapp/public>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
                AllowOverride all
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
        # error, crit, alert, emerg.
        # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
        # modules, e.g.
        #LogLevel info ssl:warn

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

        # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
        # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
        # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
        # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
        # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
        #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
</VirtualHost>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for your help. I have mad the changes you have pointed out re started apache but I still got the 404. I then rebooted the system and again still got the 404. I must have messed something up big time somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try with listening to 80 port like below?

```
Listen 80 
<VirtualHost *:80>
    <Directory /var/www/html/myapp/public>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ServerName myapp.test

    ServerAdmin info@myapp
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/myapp/public


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

My virtual host configuration is like bellow where I used 8080 port.

```
Listen 8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin info@gmail.com
    DocumentRoot "D:/appinstall/htdocs/www/app-test-server/public"
    ServerName localhost
    ErrorLog "logs/app-test-server.log"
    CustomLog "logs/app-test-server.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```